# Difference between Datafetchers and Resolvers

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am planning to implement Graphql in my spring boot application. I Googled many sites for Graphql server setup in Java and came across two ways of doing it .

One is implementing GraphQlResolver like below

```
 public class MyResolver implements GraphQLResolver<ModelX>
```

and another one is by Implementing Datafetcher
Reference: https://www.graphql-java.com

```
@Component
public class MyDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<ModelX> {


@Override
public ModelX get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Please provide some information on differences in both the approaches and best among them

Answer (score 15):

`DataFetcher` is from `graphql-java` library , the only `GraphQL` Java implementation that I known in Java world so far.

`GraphQLResolver` is from another library called  `graphql-java-tools` which is built on top of `graphql-java` . You can think that it provides a way which allow you to build a GraphQL server in a more high level way or a way that you may find more convenient. At the end , `GraphQLResolver` will somehow invoke `DataFetcher#get()` for resolving the value for a field.

An similar analogy in Spring is that `graphql-java` like Servlet while `graphql-java-tools`  like `SpringMVC`.

Comment: I prefer using GraphQLResolver over DataFetcher because there is less boilerplate code involved while using resolvers instead of DataFetchers.

Answer (score 1):

The term "resolver" is a general GraphQL term and is agnostic of any specific GraphQL implementation/framework/language. Each field in GraphQL is backed by a function called the **resolver** which is provided by the GraphQL server developer. In short, the resolver is the first logic hit to map any specific field to any specific response.

The Netflix DGS library is now open source (as of late 2020) and it introduced "DataFetchers". DataFetchers, in the DGS world, are simply a DGS-specific way of implementing resolvers.

Reading:

- [Netflix DGS Resolvers](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/datafetching/)